# Erro ao atrelar rotina ao button

Tags: android, button

Boa tarde estou tentando que um button abra uma nova activity mas quando executo o app nao abre.

**Botão**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/solare"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="254dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="358dp"
        android:background="@drawable/solo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.153"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.263" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


            button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.solare);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openActivity2();
                }
            });

        }

        public void openActivity2(){
            Intent itent = new Intent(this,Solo.class);
            startActivity(itent);
        }
```

` Aqui tento chamar ele

[ESSE E O FRAGMENT ONDE ESTA MEU BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohXLf.png)
[AQUI E A ACTIVITY DO FRAGMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8mXm.png)
[AQUI E A CLASSE MAIN ONDE TEM O MENU DO MEU APP E ONDE EU TAVA TENTANDO CHAMAR O BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5BW.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5BW.png)

Comment: Olá, Iago! Adicione um título mais descritivo à sua pergunta

Comment: O `button` está em `R.layout.activity_main`? Geralmente isso acontece quando o `findViewById()` retornar `null`

Comment: O button esta em um fragment layout

Comment: A `NullPointerException` geralmente é lançada quando o `findViewById` não encontra a view. Mova seu botão para o `layout` da `Activity` ou a lógica para o `Fragment`

Comment: Não to entendendo oq vc quer dizer com layout ! e a pasta do res ?

Comment: O `layout` é o arquivo  `xml` que representa sua UI (interface), no seu caso, o `layout` da `Activity` é o arquivo `res/layout/content_main`

Comment: Vai ficar muito extenso mas.. o button está na activity main ! Eu teria q colocar na activity que eu to tentando chamar ?

Comment: coloca o código do seu fragment, se o  button tá no fragment, é preciso chamar ele por lá

Comment: Coloquei o codigo do fragment ! tentei implementar a dica do Ivan mas n deo certo , nao sei se fiz errado !

Comment: Resolvi era como o ivan tinha explicado ! so precisei criar uma interface para gerenciar a troca de tela ! Obg pela orientação !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, Iago!

Evitando um discussão extensa nos comentários, vou tentar em uma resposta, embutir duas soluções.

Num primeiro cenário, onde o `Button` se localiza no `Fragment` como você disse

> O button esta em um fragment layout

E você está a chamar o `Button` na `Acitvity`, provavelmente receberá um erro de `NullPointerException`, pois o botão não existe no `layout` da `Activity`. Para resolver isso, mova o botão para onde ele deve ser acessado, no `Fragment`

```
public class NomeDoSeuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button mSeuButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_do_seu_fragment, container, false);

        /* ... */
        mSeuButton = view.findViewById(R.id.solares);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v.getId() == R.id.solares) {
          startActivity(new Intent(getAcivity(), ActivityDeDestino.class));
       }
    }
}
```

Num segundo cenário, onde você queira executar essas ações na própria `Activity`, apenas mova seu botão para o `layout` da `Activity` (Esses `layout`s são arquivos `xml` que representam os elementos de sua interface); O `layout` fica localizado em `res/layout/content_main`,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/solare"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="254dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="358dp"
    android:background="@drawable/solo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.153"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.263"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

E depois é só seguir como você estava fazendo, chamando o botão na `Activity`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


            button = findViewById(R.id.solare);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityDeDestino.class));
                }
            });

        }
```

No seu caso, eu acredito que a primeira solução seja a mais adequada. Espero que tenha ficado claro. Abraços!